# Postgresql - Order by varchar (cast to float) double precision exception

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to sort a list of table rows based on varchar column that contains values from null to like '1', '1.1', '9.2','12', etc...

Getting the double precision exception, while on some online postgresql database my code works.

```
select *  
from api r 
  join santa_api v on v.id = r.api_id 
order by r.api_id, r.prefix_1::float
```

Comment: You haven't included the complete and exact error message which would include the value that causes the error. But obviously there is at least one row in your table where the string value can not be converted to a `float`

Comment: Why do you store a float as text (varchar) and then cast it back to a float? Constructions like this will always cause problems and this is one of many problems you will encounter. Advice: Change the data type as soon as possible

Comment: read this **please**: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203986/29210 Converting data types reliably from text is a a whole huge bag of trouble. The function shown in that reference could save you a great deal of that trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using regex so that it only attempts the conversion when the string contains only digits, decimal points and scientific notation. i.e. Th regex below matches a string that starts with an optional plus or minus sign followed by zero or more digits. Then there may be an optional decimal point followed by one or more digits. Finally, there may be optional scientific notation consisting of the letter ‘e’ or ‘E’ followed by an optional plus or minus sign and one or more digits.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN column_name ~ '^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][+-]?\d+)?$'
        THEN column_name::numeric
        ELSE NULL
    END;
```

You could choose some other default value than NULL, that's up to you. here is a working example:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM (VALUES ('10.7'), ('2.1'), ('3.5'), ('fred')) AS t(column_name)
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN column_name ~ '^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][+-]?\d+)?$'
        THEN column_name::numeric
        ELSE NULL
    END;
```

| column_name |
| --- |
| 2.1 |
| 3.5 |
| 10.7 |
| fred |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iYR0kpSk)